# error checking not registering

Tags: java, eclipse, class

im sure theres a simple answer to this, but when i set my balance to a negative number, i want the system to print an error, at the moment, it just prints the negative number to the console, would anyone be able to help me as to why this may be happening. Any replies appreciated.

```
package Assignment1;

public class Customer
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int balance;

    public Customer(String nameParam, String addressParam, int balanceParam)
    {   
        name = nameParam;  
        address = addressParam;
        balance = balanceParam;
    }

    public void setName(String nameParam)
    {
        name = nameParam;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String addressParam)
    {
        address = addressParam;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    //I want the system to print an error should the balanceParam be less than 0
    public void setBalance(int balanceParam)
    {
        if (balanceParam >= 0)
        {
            balance = balanceParam;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid balance");
        }

    }


    public int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Customer customer1 = new Customer("Tom", "High Street", 100);
        Customer customer2 = new Customer("Mary", "Low Street", 110);

            //The balance for customer3 is set to a negative number
        Customer customer3 = new Customer("John", "Middle Street", -10);

        System.out.print(customer1.getName() + "\t");
        System.out.print(customer1.getAddress()+ "\t");
        System.out.println(customer1.getBalance());

        System.out.print(customer2.getName()+ "\t");
        System.out.print(customer2.getAddress()+ "\t");
        System.out.println(customer2.getBalance());

        System.out.print(customer3.getName()+ "\t");
        System.out.print(customer3.getAddress()+ "\t");
        System.out.println(customer3.getBalance());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the method `setBalence` which prints the error.

To have the error printed as soon as you construct the `Customer` object change your constructor to use the setter methods for the class fields

```
public Customer(String nameParam, String addressParam, int balanceParam)
{   
    setName(nameParam);  
    setAddress(addressParam);
    setBalance(balanceParam);
}
```

Also you might want to prevent the construction of such an object or setting a negative balance into an existing object by throwing an exception:

```
public void setBalance(int balanceParam) {
    if (balanceParam < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: Invalid balance");
    }
    balance = balanceParam;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the check occurs in your `setBalance()` method, but you never **call** this method. In particular, your constructor sets the `balance` field directly without a similar check One way to fix this (and reduce duplication at the same time) is to call `setBalance()` (and the other setters) from your constructor.

Comment: Thanks, i realise now what the problem is, thanks for the help